# How use button_to with params + js changes with Rails 7 [Stimulus reflex]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I want to have these events:

1. click on a specific button
2. send some params to a custom controller action
3. react changing view with js

But I'm using Rails 7 and now we have Hotwire/Stimulus Js to make it.

on the old fashioned way we did:

**views:**

```
<%= button_to "action", custom_action_path(todo), method: put, remote: true, data: {param_1: "x" } %>
```

**todo_controller:**

```
def custom_action
   # ...
end
```

**app/views/todo/custom_action.js.erb**

```
//some js changes in view
```

I know that with Stimulus Js we can do:

**view:**

```
<%#= button_to "action", nil, remote: true, 
    data: 
    { 
        controller: "charges", 
        action: "click->charges#update_installment_status", 
        charges_code_param: charge.code, 
        charges_action_param: "set as paid"
        }  
    %>
```

**charges_controller.js**

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

         update_installment_status(event) {
         //do something
          }

}
```

**but my question is**: how can I send these commands and pass data to backend controller to change the database record and only after that also modify the view using js ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use turbo_stream to update the html and then js can be attached to stimulus controller target as clarified below.

**views**

```
    <%= button_to "action", custom_action_path(todo, param_1: "x"), method: put, remote: true %>
```

**custom_action.turbo_stream.erb**

```
    <%= turbo_stream.replace("xyx", partial: "blah/blah") %>
```

If you want to run some js code you want to run after js code is executed you can add to below method

**charges_controller.js**

```
    static targets = ["xyx"]

    xyxTargetConnected(target) {
        # add the js code you want to run anytime thexyz html container is connected
    }
```